# Spring mvc how to add a variable in controller and use it as a condition in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Hi i have the following code that is executed when i submit form:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "ConController=showPayment")
public void showPayment(ActionResponse response, @ModelAttribute("conPayForm") ConsiPayForm consiForm, Model model) {
        PaymentDetailsResponse paymentDetailsResponse = stand.getDet();

           ViewDet view = stand.getView();
            ...
            PaymentDetails paymentDetails = paymentDetailsResponse.getPayDetails();
            ....        
            model.addAttribute("paymentDetails", paymentDetails);
        }
    }
```

The bean is:

```
ViewDet.class

    List <String> colours;
    List <String> design;
    ...
```

Once showPayment method is completed view.jsp is displayed and i am using jstl in the jsp. I have a view button in the jsp,
and basically I want to add a check  in the view.jsp that if  colours and design are empty then hide the view button.
Any idea how to do it from the controller please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add values in modelAndView object which is equivalent to adding in request and you need to return modelAndView from controller method.

```
     @ActionMapping(params = "ConController=showPayment")
        public ModelAndView showPayment(ActionResponse response, @ModelAttribute("conPayForm") ConsiPayForm consiForm, Model model) {
                PaymentDetailsResponse paymentDetailsResponse = stand.getDet();

                   ViewDet view = stand.getView();
                    ...
                    PaymentDetails paymentDetails = paymentDetailsResponse.getPayDetails();
                    ....        
                    model.addAttribute("paymentDetails", paymentDetails);
                    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("view"); //as per view resolver
                    modelAndView.addObject("",colorsList);
                    modelAndView.addObject("design",designList);
                    return modelAndView;
                }
            }
```

In jsp you can check these attributes using jstl

```
<c:if test="${not empty colorsList}">
... display button
</c:if>
```

[Here](http://morejava4u.blogspot.com/2013/12/html-components-in-spring-mvc.html) is some simple example.

Answer (score 0):

```
use c:if tag

test your variable in the c:if condition pass  your variables from controller and check

    <c:if test="${colors}==null&&${design}==null">
// if condition is true then it will display the button otherwise not
    <input type=button value="view"/>

    </c:if>
```

Comment: You are hitting the low quality post queue. Please elaborate.